# How can I repeat elements in place in an array in Python?

Tags: python

How can I repeat elements in place in an array in Python?

Or similarly, something more simple than this:

```
drange = [];
for i in xrange(j):
    drange.append(i);
    drange.append(i);
```

It should produce: [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, ... j-1, j-1]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> j = 3
>>> drange = []
>>> for i in xrange(j):
...     drange.extend([i]*2)
... 
>>> drange
[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2]
```

or as a list comprehension

```
>>> drange = [i for i in xrange(j) for k in range(2)]
>>> drange
[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2]
```

In some cases this method can also be appropriate

```
>>> drange = [i//2 for i in xrange(j*2)]
>>> drange
[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2]
```

Comment: If you could give the pros/cons of each method that would be excellent, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An answer using numpy

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> j = 3
>>> np.repeat(np.array(xrange(j)), 2)
array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use list comprehension then flatten the list:

```
>>> sum([ [i]*2  for i in xrange(5)],[])
[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]
```

Comment: Unfortunately using sums with lists has quadratic performance, so it doesn't scale well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a two-line alternative.

```
base=  [2*[i] for i in range(5)]
drange = [item for x in base for item in x]
```